# Upload image to the database from WP 8 page.

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I want to upload image from the WP page to the database via WCF service. I have the following service implementation that compiles fine:

```
public bool Upload(Stuff picture)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        BinaryWriter writer = null;
        string filePath;
        try
        {
            filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") +
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PictureUploadDirectory"] +
                       picture.stuffName; 

            if (picture.stuffName != string.Empty)
            {
                fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream); 
                writer.Write(picture.stuffPhoto);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
                fileStream.Close();
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

But on the WP page I have errors. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Uploading-and-downloading-images-from-WCF-in-Silverlight.aspx Here is my code:

```
private void uploadBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog(); // error 1,2 
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG files|*.jpg";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Stream stream = (Stream)openFileDialog.File.OpenRead();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

            string fileName = openFileDialog.File.Name;
            ServiceReference1.Stuff pictureFile = new ServiceReference1.Stuff();
            ServiceReference1.Stuff.stuffName = fileName; //error 3,4
            ServiceReference1.Stuff.stuffPhoto = bytes;

            ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            client.UploadCompleted += new EventHandler
           <System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_UploadCompleted); // error 5
            client.UploadAsync(pictureFile);
        }      
    }
    void client_UploadCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Result) // error 6
            {
                ResultTextlock.Text = "Upload succeeded :)";
            }
            else
            {
                ResultTextBlock.Text = "Upload failed :(";
            }
        }
    }
```

Errors are:

1,2) The type or namespace name 'OpenFileDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

3,4) An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.Stuff.stuffName.get'

5) Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

6)'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

7) The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (I have tis statement: using System.Windows.Forms;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone does not have OpenFileDialog, you have to use the [Photo Chooser task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You are referencing the `ServiceReference1.Stuff` as a static object. I think you mean `pictureFile.stuffName` etc.

The types of the event are wrong, as the error message states.

Windows Phone doesn't have Windows Forms available.

You can't just copy/paste code from Silverlight to Windows Phone and assume it works. You have to learn how to work with WP. Also these are basic errors that are explained clearly in the error messages. I suggest brushing up on the basics.

Comment: Is this the only way to upload pictures? Because I didn't find any tutorial with WCF or database input. Is there anything I can read about it?

Comment: @Leek Certainly not the only way. You can upload pictures via normal HTTP connections, TCP streams or whatever you like. Simplest one would probably be POSTing via HTTP.